# Ожидается ли в setInterval завершение вызываемой функции?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос такой: setInterval ждет окончания функции receiveComent или строго каждые 500мл вызывает ее?

```
 setInterval(receiveComent, 500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval не ждет завершения вызова предыдущей функции. Если есть опасность задержки вызываемой функции (например, длительный опрос удаленного сервер), лучше действовать на основе [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
(function loop(){
   setTimeout(function(){

      // Здесь логика
      // ...

      // Рекурсивный вызов
      loop();

  }, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызывает **по возможности** каждые 500мс.